# error, File "<ipython-input-45-3a28643f7b0c>", line 12 return random.choice(bots_greeting) ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, google-colaboratory

In the following code i am getting syntax error in the return statement

```
#function to return a random greeting to user's greeting
def greeting_response(text):
 text = text.lower()

#Bots Greeting Response
bot_greeting = ['hi', 'hello', 'how can i help you', 'welcome']
#users greetings
user_greeting = ['hi', 'hello','hey']

for word in text.split():
    if word in user_greeting:
     return random.choice(bot_greeting)
```

the error encountered while running it is:

File "", line 12
return random.choice(bots_greeting)
^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Can anyone please help me in identifying what mistake i did?
When i try to print instead of return its working fine, but with return it is giving error.

Comment: The error is what it says. Did you mean to have different indentation to bring the return statement inside your function?

Comment: Yes i want to execute it for which i think its important to bring the return statement inside. I also tried to change the indentation but nothing worked.

Comment: With print command its working fine but not with return

Comment: Does changing the indentation fix your syntax error?

Comment: No, it doesn't worked.

Comment: while using print instead of return i got a new error as below, please have a look at it as well:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d7ba8caef45e> in <module>()
      8 user_greeting = ['hi', 'hello','hey']
      9 
---> 10 for word in text.split():
     11   if word in user_greeting:
     12     print(random.choice(bot_greeting))

NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: If you have a different error with different code, you can post it all as a new question.

Comment: I agree with @quamrana, the problem is due to indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's happening due to invalid indentation. The below code should work:

```
import random


#function to return a random greeting to user's greeting
def greeting_response(text):
    text = text.lower()

    #Bots Greeting Response
    bot_greeting = ['hi', 'hello', 'how can i help you', 'welcome']
    #users greetings
    user_greeting = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']

    for word in text.split():
        if word in user_greeting:
            return random.choice(bot_greeting)


print(greeting_response('hi'))
```

I will highly recommend you to use any code editor such as [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) or [VS](https://code.visualstudio.com)

Comment: Here you import Random, i already did it in the earlier cells. Is there any difference among both

Comment: `import random` is not causing problem. Problem is due to other part of code. Like those variables and for loop is supposed to be inside `def`. A proper indentation of four whitespaces needs to be followed. Though your code logic has no issue.

Comment: the print statement is outside the defined function,right?

Comment: Right, print is outside.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about the indentation, i wan't aware about that

Comment: Can you help me in this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773699/creating-a-chatbot-that-takes-data-from-online-page-answers-accordingly-i-am>